# How to push a submodule to a remote repository

Tags: git, server, terminal

I have a remote repository set up on a server. I push from my local computer to the repository and have a hook set up to redirect the push to another directory. It looks like this:

```
post-receive

#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/laravel --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f main
```

When I go to /var/www/laravel and try to do

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

It gives:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I understand that probably I have to initiate and update the submodule before redirection the push. I probably have to create another hook command, but I can't figure out what it should be. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The post-receive script for some existing bare repository contains the line]

> ```
> git --work-tree=/var/www/laravel --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f main
> ```

[but]

> When I go to `/var/www/laravel` and try to do
>
> ```
> git submodule init
> git submodule update
> ```
>
> It gives:
>
> ```
> fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
> ```

The error itself is of course correct.  The problem is that `/var/www/laravel` has no `.git`: neither a `.git` file pointing to the location of the repository, nor a `.git` directory / folder (whichever term you prefer) containing the repository.  It is, in short, a working tree only because some other `git ...` command that *did* manipulate a Git repository contained `--work-tree=/var/www/laravel`.

The immediate solution is therefore to run:

```
git --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git submodule init
git --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git submodule update
```

or equivalent.  Note, however, that submodules involve cloning additional Git repositories, and the same reasoning—whatever it is—that led you to *not* put the Git repository itself into `/var/www/laravel/.git` in the first place might *also* lead you to avoid placing additional `.git` entries in subdirectories of `/var/www/laravel`.  This will be more difficult to achieve.

If—this is a pretty big *if*—it's OK to leave `.git` files in the submodule working trees, and if (another fairly big if) testing shows that it all works, consider having your post-receive script read:

```
# configuration: where the directory and submodules go
wt=/var/www/laravel

export GIT_DIR=$(realpath $GIT_DIR) &&
git --work-tree=$wt checkout -f main &&
cd $wt &&
git submodule update --init
```

The idea here is:

1. We take $GIT_DIR, which is set in a post-receive script but often to a *relative* path such as `.git` or `.`, and convert it to an absolute path.  (An `abspath` function would perhaps be better here, but it's less commonly available than the `realpath` command.)
2. We then use `git --worktree` to check out the commit at the tip of `main`.  The `-f` option here is needed if this might overwrite some unsaved files.  This method is highly imperfect and it would be much better to prepare a complete worktree all at once, then swap it in with a nearly-atomic `mv`, but we're sticking with the existing hook's method here.  All we did was drop the `--git-dir`, which is implicit in the `$GIT_DIR` variable anyway.
3. We then run `git submodule update --init` in the target working tree, with `$GIT_DIR` still set to the absolute path.  This combines the `init` and `update` steps.  As with the checkout step, it's rather imperfect.  We could use `git checkout --recurse-submodules` in the second step to similar effect, and that might be better in some (more recent) Git versions.

Combining the alternative (recursive checkout) with atomic swap, we get something like this instead as our post-receive:

```
wt=/var/www/laravel.update-tmp.$$
rm -rf $wt # just in case
export GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_DIR/index.tmp.$$
rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE # also just in case
mkdir $wt
git --work-tree=$wt checkout --recurse-submodules main
rm -f $GIT_INDEX_FILE

t=/var/www/laravel

# We now try to put $wt in place of $t with as little
# interruption as possible.  This means renaming the
# existing $t out of the way (using a pid-based directory
# name), renaming $wt into place, and only then removing
# (recursively) the backup.
mv $t $t.backup.$$ && mv $wt $t && rm -rf $t.backup.$$
```

The various separate lines can be strung together as one big `&&`-chain if you like, or you can use `set -e` at the top.  Note that the above is completely untested.